# Break while()-loop using UDP

Tags: c++, udp, do-while

Is it possible to do some work, such as increment a counter, in a `while()`-loop, and then break this `while()`-loop with a UDP message?

I have a Raspberry Pi 4, that is setup as a UDP-server. The programming language i'm using is C++. UDP.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>

using namespace std;

/////GLOBAL CONSTANTS/////
const int c_PORT = 8080;

class UDP
{
private:
    int fdSocketUDP_;                  //File descriptor for UDP socket
    int ClientAddressLength_;          //Length of client address
    struct sockaddr_in ServerAddress_; //Struct handling internet address for server
    struct sockaddr_in ClientAddress_; //Struct handling internet address for client

public:
    UDP();                              //Initialize and bind socket
    ~UDP();                             //Close socket
    string readUDP(const int readSize); //Read via UDP protocol (Only for blocking socket)
    void writeUDP(string message);      //Write via UDP protocol (Only for blocking socket)
};
```

UDP.cpp:

```
#include "udp.hpp"

UDP::UDP()
{
    if ((fdSocketUDP_ = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) //Create UDP socket
    {
        perror("Error - socket creation - udp.cpp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memset(&ServerAddress_, 0, sizeof(ServerAddress_)); //Sets ServerAddress_ to 0
    memset(&ClientAddress_, 0, sizeof(ClientAddress_)); //Sets ClientAddress_ to 0

    ServerAddress_.sin_family = AF_INET;         //Address family, must be AF_INET = IPv4
    ServerAddress_.sin_port = htons(c_PORT);     //PORT number, convert PORT number to network byte order using htons()
    ServerAddress_.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //IP-Address of host (server IP), INADDR_ANY gets this IP Address

    if (bind(fdSocketUDP_, (const struct sockaddr *)&ServerAddress_, sizeof(ServerAddress_)) < 0) //Bind the socket to ServerAddress_
    {
        perror("Error - socket bind - udp.cpp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

UDP::~UDP()
{
    close(fdSocketUDP_); //Close socket
}                    

string UDP::readUDP(const int readSize)
{
    char readMsg[readSize] = {0}; //Read buffer
    ClientAddressLength_ = sizeof(ClientAddress_);

    if ((recvfrom(fdSocketUDP_, readMsg, readSize, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&ClientAddress_, (socklen_t *)&ClientAddressLength_)) < 0) //Receive data via UDP protocol
    {
        perror("Error - recvfrom - udp.cpp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    string str(readMsg);           //Convert char array to string
    str = str.substr(0, readSize); //Make sure the string is the length of readsize
    return str;
}

void UDP::writeUDP(string message)
{
    //Make char array 
    int writeSize = message.size();
    char writeMsg[writeSize + 1] = {'\0'};

    //Convert string message to char array
    for (int i = 0; i < writeSize; i++)
    {
        writeMsg[i] = message[i];
    }

    if ((sendto(fdSocketUDP_, writeMsg, writeSize, 0, (const struct sockaddr *)&ClientAddress_, (socklen_t)ClientAddressLength_)) < 0) //Send data via UDP protocol
    {
        perror("Error - sendto - udp.cpp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

I have a laptop, running a Labview program. It acts as a UDP client. By sending data to the RPi from the laptop, I want to be able to break a while loop in the `main()`-function by sending specific data via UDP.

Let's say I send "111" data to the RPi from the laptop. The RPi then goes into a `while()`-loop in the `main()`-function, doing some work. I want the RPi to stay in this `while()`-loop, until I send som specific data from the Laptop. Let's say the data i want to break this `while()`-loop with is "999".

Is this possible using UDP?

Comment: Do something such as what? Call `recvfrom()`? Compute π?

Comment: Why? Why not just call `recvfrom()`? and block until it returns? That's all your loop is doing now, but in a wasteful, CPU-smoking kind of way.

Comment: Hmm, how would you block it until it returns?

Comment: Just leave the socket in blocking mode, which is how it gets created, and call `recvfrom()`. That's how it works by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Just set the socket non-blocking and periodically check if there's data received on the socket. If there is, check if it's a command to stop and, if so, stop. You can check every iteration of the loop or, if the loop repeats very quickly, every 10 or every 100 iterations.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for your answers. How do I implement this non-blocking socket? And yes, the loop repeats very quickly, so a check every 10 iterations or so is enough :-)

Comment: @jrn6270 It depends on your platform. Usually something like `int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0); fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);`

Comment: Ahh, okay. I'm using a raspberry pi, that is setup as a UDP server. The raspberry pi must do something in a while loop, until a new recvfrom() command is received from a client. But okay, I see the point in using fcntl. Thanks :-)

Comment: @jrn6270 No it musn't. It can just block in `recvfrom()`, as stated above. And `recvfrom()` isn't a 'command', it is a function you call that blocks until data arrives.

Comment: Hi again. I've updated my question with some more information. I should have done this from the start - my bad. I can't seem to get your suggestions to work though...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem thanks to @Marquis of Lorne and @David Schwartz. The solution was to use fcntl and set the socket to non-blocking.

I've updated the UDP.hpp to:

```
#pragma once

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/unistd.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>

using namespace std;

/////GLOBAL CONSTANTS/////
const int c_PORT = 8080;

class UDP
{
private:
    int fdSocketUDP_;                  //File descriptor for UDP socket
    int ClientAddressLength_;          //Length of client address
    struct sockaddr_in ServerAddress_; //Struct handling internet address for server
    struct sockaddr_in ClientAddress_; //Struct handling internet address for client

public:
    UDP();                              //Initialize and bind socket
    ~UDP();                             //Close socket
    void initNonBlock();                     //Initialize and bind socket (non blocking)
    void initBlock();                        //Initialize and bind socket (blocking)
    void closeSocket();                            //Close socket
    string readNonBlock(const int readSize);                     //read via UDP protocol with non blocking socket
    string readUDP(const int readSize); //Read via UDP protocol (Only for blocking socket)
    void writeUDP(string message);      //Write via UDP protocol (Only for blocking socket)
};
```

I've updated the UDP.cpp to:

```
#include "udp.hpp"

UDP::UDP()
{
}

UDP::~UDP()
{
    closeSocket();
}

void UDP::initNonBlock()
{
    if ((fdSocketUDP_ = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) //Create UDP socket
    {
        perror("Error - socket creation - udp.cpp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fcntl(fdSocketUDP_, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); //Set to non-blocking mode 

    memset(&ServerAddress_, 0, sizeof(ServerAddress_)); //Sets ServerAddress_ to 0
    memset(&ClientAddress_, 0, sizeof(ClientAddress_)); //Sets ClientAddress_ to 0

    ServerAddress_.sin_family = AF_INET;         //Address family, must be AF_INET = IPv4
    ServerAddress_.sin_port = htons(c_PORT);     //PORT number, convert PORT number to network byte order using htons()
    ServerAddress_.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //IP-Address of host (server IP), INADDR_ANY gets this IP Address

    if (bind(fdSocketUDP_, (const struct sockaddr *)&ServerAddress_, sizeof(ServerAddress_)) < 0) //Bind the socket to ServerAddress_
    {
        perror("Error - socket bind - udp.cpp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void UDP::initBlock()
{
    if ((fdSocketUDP_ = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) //Create UDP socket
    {
        perror("Error - socket creation - udp.cpp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&ServerAddress_, 0, sizeof(ServerAddress_)); //Sets ServerAddress_ to 0
    memset(&ClientAddress_, 0, sizeof(ClientAddress_)); //Sets ClientAddress_ to 0

    ServerAddress_.sin_family = AF_INET;         //Address family, must be AF_INET = IPv4
    ServerAddress_.sin_port = htons(c_PORT);     //PORT number, convert PORT number to network byte order using htons()
    ServerAddress_.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //IP-Address of host (server IP), INADDR_ANY gets this IP Address

    if (bind(fdSocketUDP_, (const struct sockaddr *)&ServerAddress_, sizeof(ServerAddress_)) < 0) //Bind the socket to ServerAddress_
    {
        perror("Error - socket bind - udp.cpp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void UDP::closeSocket()
{
    close(fdSocketUDP_); //Close socket
}

string UDP::readNonBlock(const int readSize)
{
    char readMsg[readSize] = {0}; //Read buffer
    ClientAddressLength_ = sizeof(ClientAddress_);

    recvfrom(fdSocketUDP_, readMsg, readSize, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&ClientAddress_, (socklen_t *)&ClientAddressLength_);

    string str(readMsg);           //Convert char array to string
    str = str.substr(0, readSize); //Make sure the string is the length of readsize
    return str;

}                    

string UDP::readUDP(const int readSize)
{
    char readMsg[readSize] = {0}; //Read buffer
    ClientAddressLength_ = sizeof(ClientAddress_);

    if ((recvfrom(fdSocketUDP_, readMsg, readSize, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&ClientAddress_, (socklen_t *)&ClientAddressLength_)) < 0) //Receive data via UDP protocol
    {
        perror("Error - recvfrom - udp.cpp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    string str(readMsg);           //Convert char array to string
    str = str.substr(0, readSize); //Make sure the string is the length of readsize
    return str;
}

void UDP::writeUDP(string message)
{
    //Make char array 
    int writeSize = message.size();
    char writeMsg[writeSize + 1] = {'\0'};

    //Convert string message to char array
    for (int i = 0; i < writeSize; i++)
    {
        writeMsg[i] = message[i];
    }

    if ((sendto(fdSocketUDP_, writeMsg, writeSize, 0, (const struct sockaddr *)&ClientAddress_, (socklen_t)ClientAddressLength_)) < 0) //Send data via UDP protocol
    {
        perror("Error - sendto - udp.cpp");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Thanks to this, i was able to break the do-while loop:

```
udp.closeSocket();
udp.initNonBlock();
do
{
    //Do something 
} while (udp.readNonBlock(3).compare("153") != 0);
udp.closeSocket();
udp.initBlock();
```

If the message sent from the UDP client is "153", it breaks the do-while loop.